# How do you delete a specific appended dictionary (i.e. its key and value) in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this output and want to delete a specific user dictionary but apparently, my code only deletes the last user appended to the list even after specifying what to delete. Help is much appreciated.

```
[{'password': '1234', 'id': 1, 'name': 'martin'}, {'password': '123',
'id': 2, 'name': 'artin'}, {'password': '134', 'id': 3, 'name':
'tin'}, {'password': '1234', 'id': 4, 'name': 'mart'}]
```

How do I delete `{'password': '123', 'id': 2, 'name': 'artin'}`

Here is my code:

```
class ClassRoom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.people= []
        self.id = 0

    def get_people(self):
        return self.people

    def add_person(self, name, password):

        self.id += 1
        self.user = {
                'id': self.id,
                'name': name,
                'password': password,
                }
        self.people.append(self.user)

    def remove_person(self, name, password):

        self.id -= 1

        if self.user in self.people:
            if self.user['name'] and self.user['password']:
                self.user.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    room = ClassRoom()
    room.add_person('martin','1234')
    room.add_person('artin','123')
    room.add_person('tin','134')
    room.add_person('mart','1234')

    print("before remove", room.get_people())

    room.remove_person('artin', '123')

    print("after remove", room.get_people())
```

Comment: What is your code? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: okey lemme post it

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but from the look at your code you're passing the dictionaries( single person) to a list, so a simple deletion of the entry in the list( whole dictionary,or person)  with either
 `self.people.pop()` or

```
self.people.remove(index).
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I figured it out.

```
def remove_person(self, id):
        self.id = id
        for self.user in range(len(self.people)):
            if self.people[self.user]['id'] == self.id:
                del self.people[self.user]
                break
```